# Do we have any idea how widespread NPIs are?

Tags: linguistic-typology, semantics

Most languages have words that function as [negative polarity items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item).  Is this believed to be true of *all* human languages?  Are there specific languages that have been plausibly claimed *not* to have any negative polarity items?

Answer (score 2):

Most languages I know have **something** like NPIs, though there is less use for at least some of them in languages like French or Yiddish that use Negative Concord.

The bibliography in [this article](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) may help, especially van der Wouden 1996, Horn and Kato 2000, and Zeijlstra, Hedde, and Soehn 2007.

Comment: Right.  Me too -- most or all of the languages I know of have something like NPIs.  It's just that I've never heard anyone explicitly say "We think this is universal" or "Here's a counterexample showing it isn't."  Which is weird, since normally us linguists are just falling all over ourselves to declare reasonably-common properties "universal." :)

I'll check out those leads, though.  Thanks!